# i want to add columns and sql query in datagridview programatically

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

nowadays am working on win form desktop application and the issue is I have 9 columns in my SQL table I want to show 7 by data table but 2 columns I want to add programmatically like every bank has amount so I want to create bank columns programmatically and want to add the amount in that columns please see the image I have added columns programmatically in data grid view but I don't know how to add the amount of each bank in that bank columns
[image]
[image]

```
string sqlCust2 = "select Dates,Rec,Name,Catt,Unit,Block,Chq,cBank from payment";
            DataAccess.ExecuteSQL(sqlCust2);
            DataTable dtCust2 = DataAccess.GetDataTable(sqlCust2);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dtCust2;
            string sqlCust3 = "select DISTINCT Bank,Amount from payment";
            DataAccess.ExecuteSQL(sqlCust3);
            DataTable dtCust3 = DataAccess.GetDataTable(sqlCust3);
            int A = Convert.ToInt32(dtCust3.Rows.Count);
            for (int i = 0; i < dtCust3.Rows.Count; ++i)
            {
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dtCust3.Rows[i][0].ToString(), dtCust3.Rows[i][0].ToString());
             
            }
```

Comment: Why do you want to make a separate query for data that is in the same table? What exactly is going wrong? And, please use some punctuation to assist readability of your question.

Comment: dear actually in my form there is Combobox to select bank but in data grid view I want to show all banks with the amount in separate columns

Comment: After you create the columns you would have to change the data source and re-bind the grid. But all of that is pointless, just put the bank info in the query to begin with. I don't know what your combobox is doing, but you can't both filter on a specific bank and also show all banks so I'm a bit confused on how your app works.

Comment: I don't need to change data source I am adding columns programmatically my works like in Combobox all banks name are there user will just select the name and add in the database and when they get data so each bank show in specific columns of that bank and amount of specific bank in that columns

Comment: I can't understand what you just said, but consider this: If you continue with your example above, you would need to populate the new columns for each row and then re-bind the grid to the data. The end result is exactly the same as if you just put the bank info into the query to begin with, except doing so is faster, easier and less error prone.

Comment: sorry dear am not be able to understand your theory how can I put the bank info into the query, to begin with, can you please clarify your answer

Comment: Add  `Bank` and `Amount` to your select statement and delete all code after: `dataGridView1.DataSource = dtCust2;`

Comment: dear with it I got duplicate columns of each bank

Comment: You don't need to call me "dear", it is awkward. The way to reference someone on SO is to do: @Tech New . If you got duplicate columns then you didn't delete the code I said to delete or you have something else going on that you have not shown.

Comment: dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dtCust3.Rows[i][0].ToString(), dtCust3.Rows[i][1].ToString());

Comment: the second column index  should be 1

Answer (score 0):

> I have 9 columns in my SQL table I want to show 7 by data table but 2 columns I want to add programmatically

Let's cut this into smaller problems. Apparently you've got some query that returns a sequence of similar object of some class. You want to show some properties of this query, but not all, you even want to show zero or more properties that are not returned  by your query.

The data fetched from the database:

```
class DatabaseRow
{
    public int A {get; set;}
    public string B {get; set;}
    public DateTime C {get; set;}
    public int D {get; set;}
    public DateTime E {get; set;}
    public int F {get; set;}
}
```

Your DataGridView shows almost the same:

```
class DataGridViewRow
{
    public int A {get; set;}
    public DateTime C {get; set;}
    public int D {get; set;}
    public DateTime E {get; set;}

    public int G {get; set;}
    public int H {get; set;}
}
```

So columns A, C, D, E are shown, but not B and F, and it also shows G and H.

Apparently you need methods to convert DataBaseRows into DataGridViewRows. Let's do this as extension methods. See [extension methods demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx).

Somehow you need new values for G and H. I don't know where you'll get them, let's suppose you fetch them from somewhere, or maybe use defaults:

```
public static DataGridViewRow ToDataGridViewRow(this DataBaseRow databaseRow)
{
    return databaseRow.ToDataGridViewRow(0, 0);
}

public static DataGridViewRow ToDataGridViewRow(
     this DataBaseRow databaseRow,
     int g,
     int h)
{
    return new DataGridViewRow
    {
         A = databaseRow.A,
         C = databaseRow.C,
         ...
         G = g,
         H = h,
    };
```

And a method to convert a sequence:

```
public static IEnumerable<DataGridViewRow> ToDataGridViewRows(
    this IEnumerable<DataBaseRow> databaseRows)
{
    return databaseRosw.Select(databaseRow => databaseRow.ToDataGridViewRow();
}
```

Your DataGridView has columns and a DataSource:

```
DataGridView dvg = new DataGridView();
DataGridViewColumn columnA = new DataGridViewColumn() {...}
DataGridViewColumn columnC = new DataGridViewColumn() {...}
...

dvg.Columns.Add(columnA);
dvg.Columns.Add(columnB);
...

IEnumerable<DatabaseRow> fetchedData = ...
IEnumerable<DataGridViewRow> dataToShow = fetchedData.ToDataGridViewRows();

BindingList<DataGridViewRow> bindingList = new Bindingist<DataGridViewRow>(dataToShow.ToList());
this.dbg.DataSource = bindingList();
```

And presto: your data is shown.

By the way, if you want to sort or filter your displayed data, consider using [nuget package Equin.ApplicationFramework.BindingListView](https://github.com/waynebloss/BindingListView)

```
var bindingList = new BindingListView<DataGridView>(dataToShow.ToList());
this.dgv.DataSource = bindingList;
```

And suddenly your data is sortable by clicking on the column header. It even shows a glyph that shows the sort order.

To filter shown data, without removing them from the bindingList:

```
var customerView = new BindingListView<Customer>(...);
this.dgv.DataSource = customerView;

// show only New Your customers:
customerView.ApplyFilter( customer => customer.City == "New York");
```